# C++ VS2010 determine if Release or Debug

Tags: c++, debugging, release

I would like to check in C++ 2010 if the build is running as Debug or Release.
Is there a simple way to check that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

VisualStudio generates `_DEBUG` and `NDEBUG` as a `define`. You can check it at compile time.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
// THE CODE IS COMPILING IN DEBUG MODE.
#endif
```